# Android debug native code "gdb.setup : No such file or directory"

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, native-code, gdbserver

I,ve been trying for almost a week now to debug the c code of the ndk sample hello-jni, but with no luck.
I have tried to follow many tutorials/blog posts on how to do this, but again with no luck.

E.g. If I follow this tutorial: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/ , I can only get to step 3, when I run the ndk-gdb it says:
"cp: cannot stat `.libs/armeabi/gdb.setup': No such file or directory"

I have comment out the last line of the ndk-gdb as described in many of the tutorials.

This is what i get when running ndk-gdb from cygwin:

> $ /cygdrive/d/data/klr200/construction/software/local/pc/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-gdb-eclipse --project=/cygdrive/d/data/klr200/construction/software/local/pc/android-ndk-r8d/samples/hello-jni --verbose --force --adb=/cygdrive/d/data/klr200/construction/software/local/pc/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe
>
> Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/d/data/klr200/construction/software/local/pc/android-ndk-r8d
> Using specific adb command: /cygdrive/d/data/klr200/construction/software/local/pc/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe
> ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
> Using ADB flags:
> Using specified project
>  path: /cygdrive/d/data/klr200/construction/software/local/pc/android-ndk-r8d/samples/hello-jni
> Found package name: com.example.hellojni
> ABIs targetted by application: armeabi
> Device API Level: 10
> Device CPU ABIs: armeabi
> Compatible device ABI: armeabi
> Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
> Using toolchain prefix: /cygdrive/d/data/klr200/construction/software/local/pc/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
> Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi
> Found debuggable flag: true
> Found device gdbserver: /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/gdbserver
> Found data directory: '/data/data/com.example.hellojni'
> Found running PID: 351
> Killing existing debugging session
> COMMAND: adb_cmd shell kill -9 496
> [1]   Killed                  run-as com.examp...
> Launched gdbserver succesfully.
> Setup network redirection
> COMMAND: adb_cmd shell run-as com.example.hellojni lib/gdbserver +debug-socket --attach >351
> COMMAND: adb_cmd forward tcp:5039 localfilesystem:/data/data/com.example.hellojni/debug-socket
> COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process obj/local/armeabi/app_process
> Attached; pid = 351
> Listening on Unix socket debug-socket
> 16 KB/s (5660 bytes in 0.329s)
> Pulled app_process from device/emulator.
> COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/linker obj/local/armeabi/linker
> 48 KB/s (39404 bytes in 0.786s)
> Pulled linker from device/emulator.
> COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/lib/libc.so obj/local/armeabi/libc.so
> 77 KB/s (273868 bytes in 3.468s)
> Pulled libc.so from device/emulator.
> **cp: cannot stat `./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup': No such file or directory**

I can't find the app_process anywhere (as I understand this is very important), and if I look in the project directory.../libs/armeabi, the gdb.setup file is there.

I'm using:

- Android NDK r8d
- Android SDK 21.1
- Eclipse Juno with CDT 8.1.1
- The latest cygwin
- Windows 7 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
The argument project="project path" is case sensitive, so when I corrected the project path it all runs perfectly.